# How to create this Search function

Tags: php, function, search, mysqli

I need to create a search function in my website, but actually I don't know where to start looking for.

In my website I have a search form and need to let the users search items like this example:

"Craft beer in Atlanta"

How to separate "Craft beer" from "Atlanta" to make the corresponding
 query?

Thanks a lot.

---

**Edit:**

Solved with This:

```
if (strpos($search, ' in ') !== false){
    $search  = $search;
    $separate = explode(" in ", $search);
    $product = $separate[0];
    $place = $separate[1];
    $query = "SELECT * from catalog WHERE (`title` LIKE '%$product%' AND `status` = 'active' AND `coverage` LIKE '%$place%') OR (`tags` LIKE '%$product%' AND `status` = 'active' AND `coverage` LIKE '%$place%') OR (`description` LIKE '%$product%' AND `status` = 'active' AND `coverage` LIKE '%$place%') order BY titulo ASC";

}
```

Comment: You need to describe your situation better. You only give 1 example, it is easy to give you an answer for that, but I guess your users queries can be very heterogeneous.

Comment: Hi! thanks for your answer, for now I only need this, then I can experiment with more complex queries :)

Comment: Use PHP's [explode](http://php.net/manual/en/function.explode.php) function

Comment: Thanks a lot! This will be so usefull for me.

Comment: Done! I've updated my question with the solution :)

Comment: @GuillermoEsquivel I removed "SOLVED" from the title. Either you post your own answer (Stack let's you do that) or just delete the question; it's your choice. Accepting a correct answer marks it as solved.

Answer (score 0):

Solved with this:

```
if (strpos($search, ' in ') !== false){
    $search  = $search;
    $separate = explode(" in ", $search);
    $product = $separate[0];
    $place = $separate[1];
    $query = "SELECT * from catalog WHERE (`title` LIKE '%$product%' AND `status` = 'active' AND `coverage` LIKE '%$place%') OR (`tags` LIKE '%$product%' AND `status` = 'active' AND `coverage` LIKE '%$place%') OR (`description` LIKE '%$product%' AND `status` = 'active' AND `coverage` LIKE '%$place%') order BY titulo ASC";

}
```